# eTrayz: Replace base system with a bootstrapped Debian

Tags: linux, debian, boot

I bought an eTrayz NAS time ago. The device is more or less good but it ships with a closed-source custom linux and a bunch of broken web-apps. I wanted to replace the whole system with a raw Debian installation.

I successfully bootstrapped a Lenny Debian into a chroot and I'm able to use use it. However I would like it to be the default system and to boot automatically at login.

The device itself ships with a bundled 2.6.24.4 kernel. I think the kernel is on a dedicated flash memory so I would prefere not to re-flash it.

What do you think is the best way to accomplish it?

Comment: Note I also have no idea of how the boot process works on this device. I don't expect it to have Grub or any known bootloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know there are similar efforts already made with similar devices like WD My Book World Edition.

I hope those tutorials and links will be helpful:

http://www.diigo.com/user/wierzowiecki/wd_world_edition%20debian (place where I collect links)

some of them:

- [How to Revive Western Digital Mybook World Edition](http://www.ismprofessional.net/pascucci/documenti/mybook/mybook-hacking-en.html)
- [My fast and perfect setup of Debian Lenny into my 500GB World Book](http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/forum/t-30649/my-fast-and-perfect-setup-of-debian-lenny-into-my-500gb-world-book)
- [Forum Category - Hacking WD MyBook World Ed Using and installing other OS's](http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/forum/c-14333/using-and-installing-other-os-s)
- ["MyLenny" firmware - Hacking WD MyBook World Ed](http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/mylenny-firmware)
- [Upgrade 500GB Blue Ring Single Disk To 1,5TB Using WD15EARS - Hacking WD MyBook World Ed](http://mybookworld.wikidot.com/upgrade-500gb-blue-ring-to-1-5tb-wd15ears)